# Renaming symlinks, using regex with boolean "|" on Linux

Tags: rename, util-linux

I have three icons: *notte* (not a symlink), astronomy (symlink) and gnome-astronomy (symlink).

```
ls -l 
astronomy.svg -> celestia.svg
gnome-astronomy.svg -> konquest.svg
notte.svg
```

I want to rename the two symlinks to notte. It should be like:

```
ls -l 
astronomy.svg -> notte.svg
gnome-astronomy.svg -> notte.svg
notte.svg
```

The `rename` command is:

```
rename -s 'celestia' -- 'notte' *.svg
```

I expected to run the commands, using regex with "|", but it did not work. Here is like:

```
rename -s -n 'konquest\|celestia' -- 'notte' *.svg 
rename -s -n 's/konquest\|celestia/notte/g' *.svg 
rename -s -n 's/\(konquest\|celestia\)/notte/g' *.svg
```

This case works only if without `-s` and if the files are not symlinks.

Comment: This is the util-linux `rename`, and not the Perl one, I take it?

Comment: Correct, @muru.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` utility of the `util-linux` package which is also known as `rename.ul` doesn't understand regexes and `-n`, but the `-s` switch.

You could rename the symlink targets in a loop with:

```
for i in konquest celestia; do
    rename.ul -s "$i" notte *.svg
done
```

The Perl `rename` script does understand regexes and `-n`, but cannot rename symlink targets.

Answer (score 0):

```
rename -s -n 's/konquest|celestia/notte/g' *.svg
```